# Create a new row for each minute of difference in Spark SQL

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Consider my data:

```
+---+-------------------+-------------------+
| id|          starttime|            endtime|
+---+-------------------+-------------------+
|  1|1970-01-01 07:00:00|1970-01-01 07:03:00|
+---+-------------------+-------------------+
```

Based on that, I want a **sql** query that creates one row for each minute of difference between endtime and start time in a way that my data ends exactly like this:

```
+---+-------------------+-------------------+
| id|          starttime|            endtime|
+---+-------------------+-------------------+
|  1|1970-01-01 07:00:00|1970-01-01 07:03:00|
+---+-------------------+-------------------+
|  1|1970-01-01 07:01:00|1970-01-01 07:03:00|
+---+-------------------+-------------------+
|  1|1970-01-01 07:02:00|1970-01-01 07:03:00|
+---+-------------------+-------------------+
|  1|1970-01-01 07:03:00|1970-01-01 07:03:00|
+---+-------------------+-------------------+
```

**I have a strong preference for sql, but if not possible, you may use pyspark.**

Comment: Show us what have you tried so far and what is not working.

Comment: That's why I came here. I have no Idea how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Spark 2.4+, you can use [`sequence`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/sql/#sequence) function to generate an array of range dates and then explode it:

```
SELECT  id, 
        explode(sequence(to_timestamp(starttime), to_timestamp(endtime), interval 1 minute)) AS starttime,
        endtime
FROM    my_table


df = spark.createDataFrame([(1, "1970-01-01 07:00:00", "1970-01-01 07:03:00")], ["id", "starttime", "endtime"])
df.createOrReplaceTempView("my_table")

sql_query = """SELECT id, 
explode(sequence(to_timestamp(starttime), to_timestamp(endtime), interval 1 minute)) as starttime,
endtime
FROM my_table
"""

spark.sql(sql_query).show()

#+---+-------------------+-------------------+
#| id|          starttime|            endtime|
#+---+-------------------+-------------------+
#|  1|1970-01-01 07:00:00|1970-01-01 07:03:00|
#|  1|1970-01-01 07:01:00|1970-01-01 07:03:00|
#|  1|1970-01-01 07:02:00|1970-01-01 07:03:00|
#|  1|1970-01-01 07:03:00|1970-01-01 07:03:00|
#+---+-------------------+-------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks. I did not know about the function sequence. I managed to do it using an udf function using lambda x: range(x), but this way is much better.

Answer (score 3):

Try this :

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
df.show()
+---+-------------------+-------------------+
| id|          starttime|            endtime|
+---+-------------------+-------------------+
|  1|1970-01-01 07:00:00|1970-01-01 07:03:00|
+---+-------------------+-------------------+

#df.printSchema()
# root
# |-- id: long (nullable = true)
# |-- starttime: timestamp (nullable = true)
# |-- endtime: timestamp (nullable = true)
```

Combination of `expr` and `sequence` with one minute interval will give you timestamp array of minutes and then `explode` it to convert in rows.

```
df.select('id', f.explode(f.expr('sequence(starttime, endtime, interval 1 minute)')).alias('starttime'), 'endtime' ).show(truncate=False)
+---+-------------------+-------------------+
|id |starttime          |endtime            |
+---+-------------------+-------------------+
|1  |1970-01-01 07:00:00|1970-01-01 07:03:00|
|1  |1970-01-01 07:01:00|1970-01-01 07:03:00|
|1  |1970-01-01 07:02:00|1970-01-01 07:03:00|
|1  |1970-01-01 07:03:00|1970-01-01 07:03:00|
+---+-------------------+-------------------+
```

Comment: good solution, i came up with a much longer and complex one, but this is faster and right to the point. will def learn from this